# Transposing text file to HTML tabular form

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have text file in linux in below format and i basically want to transpose into HTML tabular format (& sending out outbound email with the processed file content)

text_file_output.txt

```
Alias name: ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internall
Valid from: Tue Nov 12 03:58:12 UTC 2019 
Valid until: Mon Feb 10 03:58:12 UTC 2020
Alias name: ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internall
Valid from: Tue Nov 12 03:58:12 UTC 2019 
Valid until: Mon Feb 10 03:58:12 UTC 2020
```

Expecting to break the above text file content into three columns namely 
"Alias name", "Valid from", Valid until" and populate the values accordingly with values after ":" under each column

Want something like below in HTML format

Alias name| Valid from | Valid until

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO we encourage users to post their efforts in their post, so kindly do so.

Answer (score 0):

OK i made sthing which seems to work if I correctly understood your intention.
Yeah it uses temporary files.. I tried different way but didn't do it - not enough time to find out how. But it does the job so plz check it out.

input file tdata is copied from your text_file_output.txt

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -f tab_s.htm

awk '{print "<th>" $1 substr($2, 1, length($2)-1)"</th>"}' tdata > tmp_v1

cat tdata | cut -d ":" -f2,3,4 | cut -c 2- > tmp_v2
awk '$0="<td>"$0' tmp_v2 > tmp_v3
sed 's/$/<\/td>/' tmp_v3 > tmp_v2

while read e;
do
    echo "<table border="3"><tr>" >> tmp_v4;    
    sed -n '1,3p' tmp_v1 >> tmp_v4;
    echo "</tr>" >> tmp_v4;
    echo "<tr>" >> tmp_v4;
    sed -n '1,3p' tmp_v2 >> tmp_v4;
    echo "</tr></table>" >> tmp_v4
done < tmp_v2


x=$(wc -l tmp_v4 | cut -d " " -f1)
x=$((x/3))
x+="p"
sed -n "1,$x" tmp_v4 >> tab_s.htm;
rm -f tmp_v1 tmp_v2 tmp_v3 tmp_v4
```

Here is Output:

```
<table border=3><tr>
<th>Aliasname</th>
<th>Validfrom</th>
<th>Validuntil</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internall</td>
<td>Tue Nov 12 03:58:12 UTC 2019 </td>
<td>Mon Feb 10 03:58:12 UTC 2020</td>
</tr></table>
<table border=3><tr>
<th>Aliasname</th>
<th>Validfrom</th>
<th>Validuntil</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>ip-10-0-0-193.ec2.internall</td>
<td>Tue Nov 12 03:58:12 UTC 2019 </td>
<td>Mon Feb 10 03:58:12 UTC 2020</td>
</tr></table>
```

Hope this help